# How to type math multipliction symbol (×) in insert mode?

Tags: unicode

The Unicode value of multiplication sign (`×`) is `00d7`.
I can insert it using the key sequence: <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd>`u00d7`.

I want another way to generate it.

In the webpage: [Typing Vim math symbols in insert mode.](https://www.tomordonez.com/vim-math-symbols/)
indicates that we can input the division sign (`÷`) using the digraph `-:` (i.e. using the keys sequence: <kbd>Ctrl-k</kbd>`-:`).

Is there any digraph for `×`?

Comment: Is there any digraph for any glyph? The `:digraph` command lists them all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the digraph `*X` (type in insert mode <kbd>Ctrl-k</kbd>`*`<kbd>Shift-X</kbd>)

If you have the code inserted in the text using the `ga` command you'll receive more information about how to insert it and in particular if there is a corresponding digraph.

For the multiplication symbol `×` it gives:

```
<×> 215, Hex 00d7, Oct 327, Digr *X
```

You have also the possibility to add some digraph for a given decimal code.
The following command add the digraph `xx` for the multiplication symbol `×`

```
:digraph xx 215
```

### Characterize plugin:

The [vim-characterize](https://github.com/tpope/vim-characterize) plugin enrich the `ga` command:

For the multiplication symbol `×` it gives:

```
<×> 215, \327, U+00D7 MULTIPLICATION SIGN, <C-K>*X, <C-K>/\, &times;
```

Teaching you that you can also use the `/\` digraph (type in insert mode <kbd>Ctrl-k</kbd>`/\`)

### Unicode plugin:

With the [Unicode](https://github.com/chrisbra/unicode.vim) plugin you'll get additional commands:

- `UnicodeName` that could replace the `ga` command
- `Digraph` that searches the digraph for a character name
- `UnicodeSearch` that searches through the Unicode table for symbols.

The command `:UnicodeName` for the multiplication symbol `×` gives:

```
<×> U+00D7 Dec:215, MULTIPLICATION SIGN (Sm) (*X, /\) &times; /\%ud7 "\u00d7"
```

If you like it I would add the following mapping to replace the standard:

```
nnoremap ga <Plug>(UnicodeGA)
```

The command `:Digraph mult` gives:

```
× *X /\ 215
```

The `:UnicodeSearch multiplication` gives:

```
   ×    U+00D7 Dec:000215    MULTIPLICATION SIGN (Sm) (*X /\) &times;
   ⊍    U+228D Dec:008845    MULTISET MULTIPLICATION (Sm) &cupdot;
   ✕    U+2715 Dec:010005    MULTIPLICATION X (So) &#x2715;
   ✖    U+2716 Dec:010006    HEAVY MULTIPLICATION X (So) &#x2716;
   ⨰    U+2A30 Dec:010800    MULTIPLICATION SIGN WITH DOT ABOVE (Sm) &timesd;
   ⨱    U+2A31 Dec:010801    MULTIPLICATION SIGN WITH UNDERBAR (Sm) &timesbar;
   ⨴    U+2A34 Dec:010804    MULTIPLICATION SIGN IN LEFT HALF CIRCLE (Sm) &lotimes;
   ⨵    U+2A35 Dec:010805    MULTIPLICATION SIGN IN RIGHT HALF CIRCLE (Sm) &rotimes;
   ⨶    U+2A36 Dec:010806    CIRCLED MULTIPLICATION SIGN WITH CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT (Sm) &otimesas;
   ⨷    U+2A37 Dec:010807    MULTIPLICATION SIGN IN DOUBLE CIRCLE (Sm) &Otimes;
   ⨻    U+2A3B Dec:010811    MULTIPLICATION SIGN IN TRIANGLE (Sm) &tritime;
   ⫁    U+2AC1 Dec:010945    SUBSET WITH MULTIPLICATION SIGN BELOW (Sm) &submult;
   ⫂    U+2AC2 Dec:010946    SUPERSET WITH MULTIPLICATION SIGN BELOW (Sm) &supmult;
```